# Google Apps Script with multiple IF conditions

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I use this formula in Column G

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A3),"User missing",IFS(C3=E3,0,E3="","Empty Data",C3<>E3,"Wrong Data"))
```

Applying this formula for 30k data make my sheet slow. Need to convert to script.

As If and IFS is used in same formula, I am facing difficult to convert this to Script.

Condition:

```
If Column A is Empty then "User Missing"
If A have data, 
then condition is
If E is empty then "Empty Data"
If C and E is not equal then "Wrong Data"
If C and E is equal then 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that you need the columns `A,C,E` I used the range `A2:E` and paste the resulting data in column `F`:

```
function myFunction(){
    const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    const vals = sh.getRange("A2:E"+sh.getLastRow()).getValues();
    const cvals = []; 
    vals.forEach(r=>{           
         cvals.push( [
                 r[0]==''?"User Missing":
                 r[4]==''?"Empty Data":
                 r[2]!=r[4]?"Wrong Data":0
         ])            
      });
    sh.getRange(2,6,cvals.length,1).setValues(cvals); // paste in column F
}
```

Comment: Same question here, Instead C,D,E . If I use A,C,E How will be the vals?

Comment: please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65395924/edit) your question to update the conditions based on the new columns.

Comment: @Moses not sure what you edited. You want to change only the input columns? the conditions are based on columns C,D,E again? Please edit this part and change the column letters you want to use: `If Column D is Empty then "User Missing"
If D have data, 
then condition is
If E is empty then "Empty Data"
If C and E is not equal then "Wrong Data"
If C and E is equal then 0`

Comment: @Moses I updated the answer. let me know if it worked